# Select elements in list in groups of 2 - Bash

Tags: command-line, bash, ls

I am trying to select elements in a list of files using a sequence. For this I have created a list of all my files following a pattern in a folder:

```
ls -d -1 /my/path/S1*.zip
```

Where the output is:

```
/my/path/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20180412T171648_20180412T171715_021437_024E95_BDA1.zip
/my/path/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20180424T171648_20180424T171715_021612_02540A_BB21.zip
/my/path/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20180506T171649_20180506T171716_021787_025996_98AB.zip
/my/path/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20180518T171649_20180518T171716_021962_025F27_A15C.zip
/my/path/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20180530T171650_20180530T171717_022137_0264C8_5D94.zip
/my/path/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20180611T171651_20180611T171718_022312_026A3D_BBFC.zip
/my/path/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20180623T171652_20180623T171719_022487_026F7C_450E.zip
/my/path/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20180623T171652_20180623T171719_543456_64324F_452W.zip
```

I would like to create a `for`loop in which for every iteration, **the files are processed in groups of two**. So, in the first iteration, file in position 1 in my list and file in position 2 are processed. In the second interation, file in position 3 and file in position 4, etc.

To make it simpler, I will take the example of unzipping these files in grousp of 2:

```
for i in $(ls -d -1 /shared/Training/WROC0320_UrbanMapping_Germany/Original/S1*.zip)
do
unzip i
unizp i+1 # Not sure if i+1 works like that in `bash`
done
```

The problem I see with this approach is that in the first iteration it will work (`i` will be 1 and 2) but in the secodn `i` will be 2 and 3 and it should be 3 and 4.

My question is then, how to iterate over the result of `ls` is such way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should avoid iterating over the results of `ls` - see for example

- [bash pitfall #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)
- [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Compared to a `for` loop, a `while` loop gives you much more control over delimiters and file selection. For example:

```
printf '%s\0' my/path/*.zip | while IFS= read -r -d '' f1 && IFS= read -r -d '' f2; do 
  echo 'unzipping files'; echo unzip "$f1"; echo unzip "$f2"
done
unzipping files
unzip my/path/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20180412T171648_20180412T171715_021437_024E95_BDA1.zip
unzip my/path/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20180424T171648_20180424T171715_021612_02540A_BB21.zip
unzipping files
unzip my/path/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20180506T171649_20180506T171716_021787_025996_98AB.zip
unzip my/path/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20180518T171649_20180518T171716_021962_025F27_A15C.zip
unzipping files
unzip my/path/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20180530T171650_20180530T171717_022137_0264C8_5D94.zip
unzip my/path/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20180611T171651_20180611T171718_022312_026A3D_BBFC.zip
unzipping files
unzip my/path/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20180623T171652_20180623T171719_022487_026F7C_450E.zip
unzip my/path/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20180623T171652_20180623T171719_543456_64324F_452W.zip
```

Here `printf '%s\0' my/path/S*.zip` expands the shell glob into a list that is unambiguously delimited by the NULL character (the only character that may not appear in a Unix filepath), and then each `read` command reads one of them. The `IFS=` unsets the field separator - the only effect of this is to prevent the `read`s from stripping leading whitespace (in the very unlikely event that you need to handle such names).

---

A possibly cleaner way, using the `set` builtin with a shell glob to read the file names unambiguously into the positional parameter array `$@`:

```
shopt -s nullglob

set -- my/path/S*.zip
while (($# > 1)); do 
  echo "unzipping files"; 
  echo unzip "$1"; echo unzip "$2"; 
  shift 2
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to adapt it to my real application as it is slightly differnt that the example I put to make my question more clear! I'll come back with the feedback

Comment: I managed to adapt your code. Thanks for the links explaining why my first idea is not good practice. As I am new with bash, I am not understanding completely the sintax of your first line - `printf '%s\0' my/path/*.zip | while IFS= read -r -d '' f1 && IFS= read -r -d '' f2; do`. Could you please comment a little bit the logic behind? I see it works but would like to understand the idea. Thanks

Comment: @GCGM I've added some explanation plus an (I think better) alternative that uses the shell's positional parameter array

Answer (score 1):

Loop a version sorted array with step of two.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

eval \
"a=($(ls -v1 --quoting-style=shell-escape files/*))"

for ((i=0; i<${#a[@]}; i+=2)); do
    [[ -r ${a[$i]} ]] && \
        unzip "${a[$i]}"
    [[ -r ${a[(i+1)]} ]] && \
        unzip "${a[(i+1)]}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to adapt it to my real application as it is slightly differnt that the example I put to make my question more clear! I'll come back with the feedback

Comment: Thank you, your solution works also for my application but I prefer the other answer as it is a little bit easier for me to understand the sintax!